# What is type=Direct in MongoAuthority

Tags: mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

Any idea what is Direct type in MongoAuthority ?

Copy-pasting a part of, while my debuging.

```
Mongo{authority=MongoAuthority{type=Direct, serverAddresses=[127.0.0.1:27017], credentials={credentials={}}}, ... }
```

Here i see that credentials object is empty!! Is that because of direct type of Authentication?

Also, what are the different types of Authentications in mongo from java?

Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
Nilotpal

Answer (score 1):

Type.Direct specifies the type of connection between server.
There can be 2 possibilities for Type namely:

1. **Type.Direct:** In case of single server Address and
2. **Type.Set:** In case of a list server addresses.